# turn money amount to symbol equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for a method to turn a numeric value such as $10.00 into a symbol. 
I need to have symbols to represent the price of a product.

A good example is:
http://www.customink.com/categories/short-sleeve-t-shirts/16/styles#facets/

Instead of displaying prices they show currency symbols. So the price of a cheap item is represented by $ while a more expensive item is $$$

For the code it needs to:

For a value between $1-$10.99 to display it as $

For a value between $11-$25.99 to display it as $$

For a value between $26-$200 to display it as $$$

Thank you, for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: A set of if statements will probably fix this problem.

Comment: Questions simply asking for resources or provided solutions aren't really on-topic. If you would like to try implementing it yourself and get stuck, then we may be able to help with that.

Comment: Hello Greg, Thats the thing I don't know where to start. When I tried to google this question I seem to be getting search results that focus on currency converting from USD to Euro and such. I need to convert from numbers to symbols. I am not asking for a full solution. Just guidance on what I can search for. Maybe I am not searching correctly.

Comment: `"$10.00"` is not a numeric value, that's a string. This question is really two questions: How to extract numbers from a string, and how to write an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

```
var symbol;

if( value < 11.0 ) {
    symbol = "$";
}
else if( value < 26.0 ) {
    symbol = "$$";
}
else {
    symbol = "$$$";
}

return symbol
```

Or am I missing something here? There are plenty of more sophisticated approaches, but if those are actually your requirements what is wrong with an if/else clause?